# How to customize the Jenkins url without port number in linux

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins server as http://domainname.com:8080
i want that to be changed to http://domainname.com/jenkins

I am not sure in linux how to achieve this.
URL rewrite seems to be solution for windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want the port number to be part of the URL, then you must ensure Jenkins listens on the default port (ie, 80 for http). Use `--httpPort` for this.

Another option is setting up a reverse proxy (listening on port 80) which forwards requests to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins can be told explicitly on which point it should be listening on. See `--httpPort` and `--httpsPort` on [project wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins). Note that when you are running Jenkins in a managed environment (service daemon, docker container, etc.) they likely have way to configure those explicitly.

The reason why Jenkins (and in fact many other Java apps) favors 8080 is it is permitted to be used without any extra priviledges that are required for <1024 ports.

Comment: i have no issues to the port. I just dont want that to be shown as part of the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the default http port 80 traffic to Jenkins http port 8080 through ip tables.

Following are the sample commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```